# How to store up to 3GB any file in MySQL database using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have to store the PDFs, Videos, and images files in MySQL database.
Whether I store file path or file as a blob? What's better? If I had to store files in GB's How would I store?

I'm able to store files in blob but less than 10 Mb only.

Comment: Store the file in the filesystem and the file path in the database.

Comment: Path of course. (but: MySQL should be able to handle >10MB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing files is IMHO always a bad idea store your files somewhere on the file system and store only the path to the file in your database.

On big sites are always servers for file storage and other machines for databases. That scenarios have different requirements.

About the 10mb limit I guess that is caused by a server setting. I think 10mb is the default setting in PHP.